# Passing an Array from LWC to Flow

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, visual-workflow

I´m trying to pass an Array from my LWC to a Flow, in wich it is embeded as a screencomponent.

This is my meta.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>55.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="sumAll" type="Integer" label="Sum"/>
            <property name="arrSums" type="{Integer[]}" label = "Arr_Single_Values"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

I can see both properties in the Flow, but when I associate a picklist with it get the error that the output parameter is not of the same type as the Flow-Variable.

Comment: Can you please explain what the array contains?

Comment: The Array, called "arrSums", just contains a few integers.

Comment: Why do you have braces around the `Integer[]` type specification?

Comment: Also, why do you think a picklist is an integer array?